# Filter column value from multiple csv files using python(pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, filter

CITY_DATA = { 'chicago': 'chicago.csv','new york city': 'new_york_city.csv','washington': 'washington.csv' }

Asks user to specify a city, month, and day to analyze.

```
Returns:
    (str) city - name of the city to analyze
    (str) month - name of the month to filter by, or "all" to apply no month filter
    (str) day - name of the day of week to filter by, or "all" to apply no day filter
```

To DO:get user input for city (chicago, new york city, washington). HINT: Use a while loop to handle invalid input

Here is top 5 rows of chicago below which is one of 3 csv file. My question is there are total 3 csv files for each city. How can I filter column value(city/month/day) from different files? If using loop, it seems wrong that I use if, elif,elif.... for all cities or 12 months or 7 days. Sorry, I am new to Python and I am dizzy for this. Please help with a answer or a hint. Thanks.

```
            Start Time             End Time  Trip Duration  \
0  2017-05-29 18:36:27  2017-05-29 18:49:27            780   
1  2017-06-12 19:00:33  2017-06-12 19:24:22           1429   
2  2017-02-13 17:02:02  2017-02-13 17:20:10           1088   
3  2017-04-24 18:39:45  2017-04-24 18:54:59            914   
4  2017-01-26 15:36:07  2017-01-26 15:43:21            434   

                  Start Station                          End Station  \
0     Columbus Dr & Randolph St                 Federal St & Polk St   
1        Kingsbury St & Erie St  Orleans St & Merchandise Mart Plaza   
2         Canal St & Madison St              Paulina Ave & North Ave   
3  Spaulding Ave & Armitage Ave       California Ave & Milwaukee Ave   
4        Clark St & Randolph St         Financial Pl & Congress Pkwy   

    User Type  Gender  Birth Year  
0  Subscriber    Male      1991.0  
1    Customer     NaN         NaN  
2  Subscriber  Female      1982.0  
3  Subscriber    Male      1966.0  
4  Subscriber  Female      1983.0
```

What is wrong with the code below? Should place city=input('Enter a city') after if statement? confused.

```
import time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

CITY_DATA = { 'chicago': 'chicago.csv',
             'new york city': 'new_york_city.csv',
             'washington': 'washington.csv' }
def get_city():
    print("Hello! Let's explore some US bikeshare data! \n Which city would you like? \n Chicago, New York City or Washington? ")
cities = ['chicago', 'new york city', 'washington']
city = input('Enter a city: ')
Enter a city: san jose

if city == 'chicago':
    return chicago
elif city == 'new york city':
    return new_york_city
elif city == 'washington':
    return washington
else:
    print ('Ops, your enter is out of range.')

File "<ipython-input-14-335bd5bdf8dc>", line 2
    return chicago
    ^
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function
```

Comment: Where is your data?

Comment: Please put it in the question where it won't suffer from severe formatting errors.

Comment: How to put data here? There are 3 big csv files. Here are column names and first row.                                                                             Start Time End Time Trip Duration Start Station End Station User Type Gender Birth Year
6/23/2017 15:09 6/23/2017 15:14 321 Wood St & Hubbard St Damen Ave & Chicago Ave Subscriber Male 1992

Comment: Edit your question and add the first 5-10 rows.

Comment: `HINT: Use a while loop to handle invalid input`. Is this your hint? Or the rules of your assignment provided by your teacher?

Comment: hint from the project. But I can use whatever is easier.

Comment: coldspeed, thanks for the nice format.

Answer (score 0):

This is the data analysis project for Udacity. This is how I did it.

```
import time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

CITY_DATA = { 'chicago': 'chicago.csv',
              'new york city': 'new_york_city.csv',
              'washington': 'washington.csv' }

def get_filters():
    """
    Asks user to specify a city, month, and day to analyze.

    Returns:
        (str) city - name of the city to analyze
        (str) month - name of the month to filter by, or "all" to apply no month filter
        (str) day - name of the day of week to filter by, or "all" to apply no day filter
    """
    print('Hello! Let\'s explore some US bikeshare data!')

    cities = ['chicago', 'new york city', 'washington']
    cond = 0
    while cond != 1:
        city = input("Which city would you like? ")
        city = city.lower()
        if city in cities:
            cond = 1
        else:
            cond = 0



        # TO DO: get user input for month (all, january, february, ... , june)
    months = ['all' , 'january', 'february', 'march','april','may','june','july','august','september''october','november','december']
    cond = 0
    while cond != 1:
        month = input("Which month would you like? ")
        month = month.lower()
        if month in months:
            cond = 1
        else:
            cond = 0



        # TO DO: get user input for day of week (all, monday, tuesday, ... sunday)
    days = ['all', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday','sunday']
    cond = 0
    while cond != 1:
        day = input("Which day would you like? ")
        day = day.lower()
        if day in days:
            cond = 1
        else:
            cond = 0



    print('-'*40)
    return city, month, day
```

Comment: Thanks. I am not really understand what cond =0 and cond=1 mean.

Comment: It is the conditional statement for the while loop. You could use boolean values instead. The while loop runs until input accepted is one of the user inputs given days, months or cities.

Comment: You need to use a while loop because the person can make multiple invalid attempts at the city. I set the city input to city.lower() because then Chicago is chicago.